# create react native app expo failed to connect running on emulator in same computer

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, expo, create-react-native-app

I'm new to react native, I've used *create-react-native-app* command to generate a project, executed *npm start* to start the packager. Until now all is good, the packager is running on address 192.168.232.56:19000, it shows me the QR code and the menu, but when I hit **a** to start the app in the emulator, the expo app shows:

**Something went wrong, could not load exp://192.168.232.56:19000**

with the log stating

**ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.232.56:19000**

usning the browser in the emulator I can freely surf the internet, so there is connection

Any help greatle appreciated!! (just to clarify, the emulator is running in the same computer where I develop and the packager is running)

**UPDATE:** accessing address *10.0.2.2:19000* from the browser in the emulator throws the following json:

```
{
    "sdkVersion": "27.0.0",
    "name": "template",
    "slug": "template",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "xde": true,
    "developer": {
        "tool": "crna",
        "projectRoot": "/home-root/repo/template"
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
        "hostType": "tunnel",
        "lanType": "ip",
        "dev": true,
        "minify": false,
        "urlRandomness": null
    },
    "env": {},
    "bundleUrl": "http://localhost:19001/./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2Fhome-root%2Frepo%2Ftemplate%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles",
    "debuggerHost": "localhost:19001",
    "mainModuleName": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry",
    "logUrl": "http://localhost:19000/logs",
    "id": "@anonymous/template-a79d4723-c675-4546-8d61-74b0a969417f"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Expo XDE. If that doesn't work, try changing the host type. Restarting everything might also help you, as well as clearing the packager cache. If nothing works, might be your firewall is blocking ports 19003 to 19000, but I believe that shouldn't be a problem, since you are running a local emulator